# How to recreate java classes from .class?

Tags: java, maven

I have a few package with a lot of **.class** java classes, can I somehow recreate with idea? Or maven?

Or what can I do to work my main class which is use this .classes but dont' see it because of the .class extension?

I tried to change the .class extension to .java but the encoding will be wrong...cannot read it after rename to .java..

Or may be make a dependency from it? Or what is the best solution?

I have this main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake snake = new Snake();
        snake.addAI(new MintaAi(), Color.red.darker());
        snake.addAI(new MintaAi(), Color.blue.darker());
        snake.start();
    }
}
```

And I have to run it but everything what I need is .class extension.

Comment: what you need is a java decompiler, since the class files are not java code, but java byte code, maybe even obfuscated.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. But one tip for the future: most browsers support spell checking nowadays. You might want to enable that, to help with having less of this redly underlined typsos in your text ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about some 3rd party input that comes as .class files; one easy way to *view* the Java source code is to put those class files into a JAR file; and add that JAR file to your project setup in IntelliJ. When you know press "F3" on a class coming out of that library, IntelliJ will decompile the class file content and show it to you.

Alternatively, you can look into command line tools doing that for you, for example [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/). You have to understand that all such technology is limited to a certain degree. When the byte code was touched by an obfuscator for example, a decompiler might have a very hard time showing you anything useful.

But the real answer is: you want to step back and learn a bit about the concepts you intend to use. Like ".java" means Java source code; and .class means "bytecode, compiled from Java source code".

And of course: when Snake, or MintaAi are classes that *you* wrote; then *you* should have the source code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks...i created a jar from this classes and add to the libraries...and now it is running...thanks for the help again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use bytecodeview http://bytecodeviewer.com/. It contains several types of decompilers. You can change decompiler and see preview of quality of decompiled code. In case if code amount small and is not compicated it works well.

Bad parts are: generics (type erasure), very bad parts is reflections(proxy invocations), really bad parts is there is bytecode injections used in class files.